# “Ich gehe abends oft aus.” – where to put “nicht” for negating?

Tags: word-order, separable-verb, negation

I want to answer the question “Gehen Sie abends oft aus ?” and say that I don’t like to go out at evenings. I am confused where to put *nicht* in my answer. I know that *nicht* has to negate *oft* so it must come before it.

Is it valid then to say the following?

> Nein, ich gehe abends nicht oft aus.

Comment: Your suggestion is absolutely fine.

Comment: The sentence sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sentence that you want to negate:

> Ich gehe abends oft aus.
>   I often go out at evening.

There are two possible positions to insert »nicht« to negate the sentence. It's before »oft« and behind »oft« (same in english):

> Ich gehe abends **nicht** oft aus.
>   I **don't** often go out at evening.

This is the most usual way. But there is also a second position where »nicht« is allowed:

> Ich gehe abends oft **nicht** aus.
>   I often **don't** go out at evening.

In this second case you often want to at some additional information:

> Ich gehe abends oft **nicht** aus, *weil ich es mir nicht leisten kann*.
>   I often **don't** go out at evening *because I can't afford it*.

Comment: As a note: Actually it would be "*in the evening*" or you could say "*at night*". Also it should be *"I don't often go …*".